# PHP: how to move array pointer inside foreach loop?

Tags: php

```
$animals = array('cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'elephant');
foreach($animals as $animal)
{
   var_dump($animal);
   next($animals);
}
```

The code above outputs: cat, dog, horse, elephant. I thought the `next` function should move the internal pointer of `$animals` and, thus, I should be getting this output instead: cat, horse.

How do I make the internal pointer of $animals move forward (and backwards) such that it is affected in the foreach?

EDIT 1:

From the manual:

> As foreach relies on the internal array pointer changing it within the
>   loop may lead to unexpected behavior.

Nonetheless, I think this is what I need to do.

EDIT 2:

Per "Your Common Sense"'s link, I will provide a more detailed explanation of my problem. Here's some psuedo code:

```
array $foos;

start loop of $foos
 - do thing #1
 - do thing #2
 - do thing #3
 - keep doing thing #3 while the current value of $foos in the loop meets a certain criteria
loop
```

When execution returns to the start of the loop, it should continue from the last array accessed by #3. **Note that the array is associative**, thus a `for ($i = 0 ...` approach won't work.

Comment: this is not an explanation of the real life task but the same xy problem. WHY do you need that?

Comment: There is probably a cleaner design hidden somewhere in this implementation detail concern

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just create an [`ArrayIterator`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/ArrayIterator)  which is [`seekable`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/SeekableIterator).

As it is an iterator, you can change the **position** *while* you iterate over it, some rudimentary example:

```
foreach ($iterator as $current) {
    $iterator->next();
}
```

It should offer everything you need out of the box. If not, you could **encapsulate** your needs into an [`Iterator`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/class.iterator) on your own as well.

Answer (score 8):

You shouldn't mix `foreach` with direct pointer access. If you want to move around in the array, just replace the `foreach` with a C-style `for`.  It's wordier at the top, but works with an identical loop body to the `foreach` case, with the difference being that you can muck with the internal pointer and have the desired result.

```
$animals = array('cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'elephant');
for ($animal = current($animals), $index = key($animals); 
       $animal; 
       $animal = next($animals), $index = key($animals)) {
  print "$index:";
  var_dump($animal);
  next($animals);
}
```

Output:

```
0:string(3) "cat"
2:string(5) "horse"
```

It's very misleading to use a straight-through iteration construct like `foreach` when you're actually moving around back and forth within the array.  The above `for` loop is better in this regard, but not by much; a `while` loop, with all the details explicitly spelled out in the loop body, might be the best choice.

Comment: Mark, I've updated the original question to explain a bit better what I am trying to do. Hope it helps.

Comment: The above for() loop behaves exactly like a foreach() loop over an array.  If you're doing `as $key => $value`, then you just need to add a call to `key` as well, which I have now done.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the 2nd parameter in your for-loop. Is that even valid syntax?

Comment: It's valid - the code works as written.  What's your question?  We can chat if you like.

Answer (score 6):

Mark's solution is pretty close but fails if the array contains values like 0, false or "" which evaluate false in the second for loop expression.

This solution works for all arrays and is a bit closer to the "spirit" of a for loop. The reset() in the first loop expression ensures we start at the beginning of the array which would be the case with foreach. The second expression in the for loop needs to evaluate if the element the array pointer points to exists. key() returns null if the array pointer points beyond the end of the array or the array is empty. The third expression advances the array pointer at the end of each iteration.

```
$animals = array('cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'elephant');
for (reset($animals); key($animals) !== null; next($animals)) {
    $animal = current($animals);
    var_dump($animal);
    next($animals);
}
```

This outputs:

```
string(3) "cat"
string(5) "horse"
```

Comment: It actually looks like a for loop, can be used in lots of situations, and solves the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add `&` to value

```
foreach ($variable as $key => &$value) {

}
```

Now `$value` reference to `$variable[$key]` address

Comment: This is very usefull when you want to update the values of the array when you do a foreach loop. The other way would be to reference it in a for loop with something like `$variable[$key] = 'MyNewValue';`

Answer (score 0):

I think cause he just wants to skip elements, he could use 'continue' combined with an if-clause inside the foreach.

```
$skip=array ('dog', 'elephant');
$animals = array('cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'elephant');
foreach($animals as $animal)
{
   if (in_array($animal, $skip)) {
       continue;
   }
   var_dump($animal);
}
```

this will output:

```
string(3) "cat" 
string(5) "horse"
```

Variante 2 without continue with the same effect:

```
$skip=array ('dog', 'elephant');
$animals = array('cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'elephant');
foreach($animals as $animal)
{
   if (!in_array($animal, $skip)) {
        var_dump($animal);
   }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to increment the pointer manually at the end of a foreach loop - it's done automatically. You don't need anything more than:

```
foreach($animals as $animal) {
    var_dump($animal)
}
```

Comment: OP is trying to skip elements, @andrewsi.

Comment: I know, but I really want to advance the pointer to the next item. Refer to the example output I am expecting in the original post.

Comment: Memo to self: stackoverflow and insomnia do not mix