# Moving pointer when array is passed as reference

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

How can we move the pointer forward or backward in a `foreach` statement when array is passed as reference :

```
foreach($array as $key => &$val){

   if($condition1 == true) **set pointer to previous element**
    else **set pointer to previous to previous element**;

   if($condition2 == true) **set pointer to next element**
    else **set pointer to next to next element**;
}
```

Edit1: If I use `ArrayIterator` I have to change a lot of code, which I want to avoid.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458848/php-how-to-move-array-pointer-inside-foreach-loop

Comment: If I use `ArrayIterator` I have to change a lot of code, which I want to avoid.

Comment: imo, However, there is nothing preventing you keeping  'previous' and 'next' pointers yourself and using logic in the `foreach`. I would be tempted to write a `class` to do the logic you require. I suspect it wiil be a lot easier than 'fighting' with `foreach` long term. see 'collections'?

Comment: @RyanVincent You are right.

Answer (score 0):

With no other simple solution I finally modified the code to implement `ArrayIterator` class and changed the program logic

```
$obj = new ArrayObject( $arrayName );
$it = $obj->getIterator();
foreach ($it as $key=>&$val){
  if(condition1){
    $it->offsetSet($it->key()+1,$arrayName[$key+2]);
  }
}
```